怎么理解 troll factories
Source from https://weibo.com/2524408051/OD0QeinKo

It's entirely clear why the change was done, it's not getting reverted, and using multiple random anonymous accounts to try to "grass root" it by Russian troll factories isn't going to change anything.

为什么要这样改原因很明确，我们也不会撤回这个提交。就算这样用一堆俄罗斯巨魔工厂里整来的匿名账号群起而攻之，结果也不会改变。


想问下把troll factories翻译为巨魔工厂，是不是翻译错误了，这样的句子不通顺，也很难理解，巨魔工厂是什么？
附一张图片：


巨魔工厂 is a literal translation of troll factories.
巨魔 is troll’s original meaning as in Scandinavian folklore, while troll here is a slang for annoying people online who post offensive messages. Yes, I find this translation stupid as well but it’s not uncommon.
By 工厂, Linus wants to say those troll users are specifically made and organized in Russia.
Maybe 水军 sounds more natural as the translation.
Update: After looking at the sentence, I think 水军基地 is better for the context.

Thank you for your answer. troll理解为水军的话感觉更自然些。

巨魔 is the official translation of "troll" - "a dwarf or giant in Scandinavian folklore inhabiting caves or hills", which isn't what the author meant - "someone who intentionally antagonizes others online by posting inflammatory, irrelevant, or offensive comments or other disruptive content".
Here are a few names for "troll" on the web such as: "五毛(50 cents)", "喷子(sprayers/spouters)". and "杠精(pry bar spirits)", but none is universally accepted.

Thank you for your answer. Regarding "troll factories," what are your thoughts on the term "factories"?

@Tom It's a troll farm. The term "troll factory" exists in English too, although it's less common. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_farm

@TeleportingGoat  Thank you for pointing that out. I previously searched for the meanings of "troll" and "factory" separately, but I didn't search for "troll factory" directly. I really appreciate your link!
